# TFS AD Sync not syncing on AD-group rename

Tags: tfs

Good day guys,

yesterday we just wanted to change some AD-Group names and their descriptions. We synced about ten times, but only strange things happened:

- We can´t find the renamed group in tbl_identity
  => We can only find the old group
- If we are searching the new group in TFS-Webinterface we can find the new group name, but if we add it to a project only the old name/description is shown.

Our TFS: 2018.1

Does anybody have an idea?

Thx a lot guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS use a background synchronization job, scheduled every hour, to look for changes in Active Directory (or the local machine workgroup if the server is not domain joined). So changes you make to local or Active Directory groups do not get reflected in TFS immediately. Instead, TFS will synchronize those groups regularly (by default every hour).

TFS records SID of the groups in the AD,  no matter how the account/goup name change, its SID remains the same.  TFS synchronizes with AD depend on SID.

It directly retrieve the group information from AD but not tfs DB when you search the group in web interface. So you can get the new group name.

In you scenario, you can try to **force TFS to sync with Active Directory** with the ways mentioned in below articles:

- [Force TFS to sync with Active Directory](https://blogs.msmvps.com/vstsblog/2011/02/17/force-tfs-to-sync-with-active-directory/)
- [How to synchronize TFS users with AD (Active Directory)?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24305.how-to-synchronize-tfs-users-with-ad-active-directory.aspx)

---

**Further Troubleshooting:**

Mr. Hinsh has a good [troubleshooting guide](https://nkdagility.com/active-directory-groups-not-syncing-with-team-foundation-server-2010/) if you still have troubles.

Comment: Yep, as i thought...think the main problem is that TFS only syncs depending on SID... And does not check if there are changes in other properties of the group - means names and stuff are not updated if you change them in AD.
Also means that you can find the renamed group but tfs is showing old stuff :(

Comment: @Chrizzo  So what was the answer?  Was it in the "Further Troubleshooting" guide?  The main answer doesn't make sense to me, because it says that synchronizing TFS with A/D doesn't solve the problem, and then in almost the same breath seems to say that the answer is to force synchronization of TFS with A/D.

Comment: What i found out was that the renaming didn´t synchronize for some days. Also not when i synced manually. Another day i looked about it, it was synchronized - but don´t ask me why :(

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem with TFS 2018.  A group renamed in AD would not change the group name in TFS.  I could delete the group from TFS security permissions for the project, add it back by searching the new name in AD, but when soon as I refreshed the page the old name (that did not exist anymore in AD) would appear.

I found a solution that worked.  Make a new group called whatever, say "TFS_fix", and nest the renamed group into it.  Put "TFS_fix" into a security permission and wait for TFS to sync with AD.  When that happened, the renamed group correctly updated its name.  Once the name updates you can remove "TFS_fix" from the TFS security permissions and remove the renamed group from "TFS_fix".

This worked with every change we needed to make with TFS 2018.

Andrew B